# Capture words that mouse selects by cpp

Tags: c++, screen-capture

Now I have a requirement，The platform  is windows, I need to capture the text that mouse selects by c++ ，When then mouse selects some words, I can get them real time, the same function like [this product](http://download.deskperience.com/WordCaptureSetupDemo.exe) .

I think it's a mouse event, but I haven't found some useful API, Is somebody can help me? Thank you!

Comment: Unanswerable without the platform for which you are developping. The answers will be radically different on Windows, Mac, a dozen different *nix desktop environments....

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific about the API requirement and the platfom.
For windows for instance: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649022(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: oh, I think it's not what I want, I need to get the text when the mouse  selects, or may be I will add some key listener like when they press ctrl, not mean get the text from clipboard